# fullCalendar - pass view.start data to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

When all the events in the calender has been rendered (`eventAfterAllRender`) - I like to pass the `view.start` to ajax but it will not work - I get an error on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'getFullYear'
```

However this do work:

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
  alert(view.start);
}
```

Full code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false,
    events:  { 
        url:    'calender-sales-events.php',
        data: {
            selectReportBy: $(".SelectReportBy").val(),
        }
    },
    firstDay:1,
    eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
        $.get("calender-overview.php", { start:  view.start } , function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
    $.get("calender-overview.php", { start:  view.start } , function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

should be

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
    $.get("calender-overview.php", { start:  $(this).fullCalendar().visStart } , function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'getFullYear'
Judging by your error it looks like you are trying to call a date function on a non date object. Try to fix that first.